# Delete Audio From Sdcard

Tags: android, audio, storage, delete-file, sd-card

I'm trying to delete an audio file in the SD-card but I'm not successful

```
public boolean delete(String path)
{ 
   return new File(path).delete();
}
```

While going through posts I came across `Storage Access Framework` but unable to understand. Is it required for deleting files from SD-card?
Moreover Can I only use Content Resolver to delete Files Like this?

```
getContenResolver().delete(uri,null,null);
```

Or is there any other method for deleting Audio?
My app is well elevated with `Write permission` and `Read permission` and I am testing on `Marshmallow 6.0`

Please answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Moreover Can I only use Content Resolver to delete Files Like this?

getContenResolver().delete(uri,null,null);`. Have you ever tried that? And did it work?

Comment: @greenapps just found it in one of the post .let me try

Comment: @greenapps tried but it only deletes it from the the Mediastore table not actually from storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure two things:

1) Since you are targeting Android.M you need to get permissions on runtime as well. Simply asking for them in the Manifest is not enough.

2) if you want to read/write data on SD card you need to use DocumentFile instead of File. The logic is more or less the same but you can refer here for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html

---

Use this command in your OnCreate or anywhere you wish, to open a dialog that let's you select an SD directory. Select the one where your image is.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), 42);
```

Then you will need this method as is:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent resultData) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;
        Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
        DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
        grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

        DocumentFile YourAudioFile=  pickedDir.findFile("YourAudioFileNameGoesHere");


// And here you can delete YourAudioFile or do whatever you want with it

}
```

Comment: With DocumentFile one does not need those permissions.

Comment: The first one was like a general advice even if not applicable in this scenario, cause i sensed a certain self-complacence by the use of "My app is well elevated with Write permission and Read permission" which could lead to future mistakes. ;)

Comment: @SotirisM.Magionas do i need get the sd card uri or something like that or just a document file object is enough??

Comment: @SotirisM.Magionas is this code OK: document=DocumentFile.singleFileUri(context,Uri.parse(path)); document.delete();

Comment: @SotirisM.Magionas not working the above code .Any other method

Comment: Better use `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to choose the file itself. As then you have directly the uri for the file.

Comment: @DibyaranjanMishra Were you able to resolve your issue? If yes, please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: i was not it is showing nullpointer exception pointing at the method file.delete () but i checked my uri is is perfect and the file name also but no use

Comment: You do have those permissions in your manifest, right?

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />

Comment: I have tested my code and it works. Please tell me you replaced "YourAudioFileNameGoesHere" with the actual name of your audio file.

Comment: yes i have the permission and does name needs to be followed by extension