# How to save files at the root of SD card (android 8.0+)?

Tags: android, android-storage

I'm trying to create a folder at the root of an external SD Card (and to later put in there the files generated by my app).

I'm asking WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission but I think it's not enough to actually write on the external SD card.

Here's my code :

```
private boolean authorized = false;
private final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        long debut = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            debut = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else {
            authorized = true;
        }
        while (!authorized) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                authorized = true;
            } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() - debut >= 5000) {
                this.finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

//SDCARD path = "/storage/9016-4EF8"
new File("/storage/9016-4EF8"+"/MyApp").mkdirs();
}
```

My code works on my phone (android 5.1), but not on my tablet (android 8.1). It seems like I only have a read permission on the latest versions of android.
How do i get the write permission on the SD card?

I'm using a File explorer App, Xplore, and this app seems to ask for another permission before being able to modify files on the SD Card :

"grant Xplore access to your data, including photos and videos, on sd card"

How can i ask for this permission (if it's even possible)?

Comment: "How do i get the write permission on the SD card?" -- you don't, particularly on Android Q and above. Use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) and let the user choose where the content goes.

Comment: The thing is I don't want the user to be able to choose, I need my files in a fixed location, easy to find on the SD Card

Comment: No my friend this is a bad practice and Google doesn't allow it no more. The user has to choose the folder. What you COULD do is ask the user (using a dialog or something) to choose the root folder of the SD thus giving you access to any child of that folder which of course means the entire SD card.

Comment: Well, I was asked to save all the files this way.
If I save the returned URI somewhere, will I keep the rights to write?

Comment: "I was asked to save all the files this way" -- talk to whoever gave you that requirement and explain that this is not how it works on Android. "I need my files in a fixed location, easy to find on the SD Card" -- you are welcome to use `getExternalFilesDirs()`. If that returns 2+ locations, all but the first will be on removable media. It will not be the root of the removable media, though. "If I save the returned URI somewhere, will I keep the rights to write?" -- you can use `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on `ContentResolver` for a `Uri` you get from the Storage Access Framework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are correct! It is not enough if you want to access the SD card. You need to use a `documentFile`.

See my answer to an older question about SD cards to understand how to access your SD card [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527106/delete-audio-from-sdcard/48528465#48528465).

Comment: No content provided, no examples. If this question is up and open you shall answer by giving an example. Otherwise this is a duplicate of the question you posted