# How to get permission to write files into SDCard in Android 6.0+

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdcard

I'm developing a simple file explorer to list and write files. It works perfectly on internal storage, but not on external SD Card (access denied for writing files).
I have these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I request them when the app starts. But I still can't save files on the external SD.
When I try to write using `FileOutputStream`, it throws a `FileNotFoundException` using the path `/storage/(sdcard folder)/`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/27BB-C7D9/Download/353874.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Is SD card read only on Android?
Some apps, like ES File Explorer can write files on external SD. Is there some functionality that I can use to get enough permissions?

Thanks.

Comment: add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in application section

Comment: as far as I know, you only can use SAF now to write to real physical SD card

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko what could be that 'SAF'?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya add on AndroidManifest.xml file?
I tried it but that is an unknown attribute for application section.

Comment: @LuanSilveira have you tried searching for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `documentFile`.

See my answer to an older question about SD cards to understand how to access your SD card [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527106/delete-audio-from-sdcard/48528465#48528465).

Comment: instead of answering with a link you should mark question as duplicate

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir1/dir2");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename");
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: That won't work if you don't request the runtime permissions, which will most likely be insufficient with Android Q too anyway.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() does not points to SD Card. It points to '/storage/emulated/0/', that is the internal storage.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` won't give you path to physical SD card, it will return emulated SD card.

Answer (score -1):

Above API level 23 you have to request it at runtime

```
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
requestPermissions(permissions, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Now override the onRequestPermissionsResult method like so

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // write here
            } else {
                 // show message to user that permission needed
            }
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: But I already do it! I request those permissions when app starts.
I wrote it in the question: 
"I have these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file:
[...]
and I request them when the app starts."

Comment: @LuanSilveira you have to have that in the AndroidManifest.xml and on top of that you have to do the above at runtime

Comment: @tiborK Please read the question carefully: it is about writing to **external physical SD card, like microSD**. It is not permission-related